# Installation issue: Directory bin in server/dynamodb-titan100-storage-backend-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT-hadoop1 does not exist

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, titan, tinkerpop, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gremlin-server

I have been trying for a couple of days to install Aws DynamoDB Titan Storage Backend on Windows Subsystem Linux without any success. I am using the following instructions `http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.TitanDB.DownloadingAndRunning.html`

Am currently stuck at step 5, where i am supposed to install gremlin server using the following command

```
src/test/resources/install-gremlin-server.sh
```

The command runs successfully without any error, but when i try to run the next command 
`bin/gremlin-server.sh ${PWD}/conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server-local.yaml`
after changing directory to 
`server/dynamodb-titan100-storage-backend-1.0.0-hadoop1` 
it fails because the directory bin does not exist, upon lookup, only two directories exists (badlibs and ext). I have searched for a solution in vain, hopefully someone will help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to install gremlin, you need to do it as root in linux, otherwise it won't work. I repeated the procedure with root and everything worked. Also in order to run it, you also need to run it as root, otherwise you will run into some problems